# Exporting SQL Query results to Excel

Tags: sql-server, export

On executing the below mentioned statement:

```
EXEC proc_generate_excel_with_columns 
     'your dbname', 'your table name','your file path'
```

I'm getting the following error.Can anyone help?

> User name not provided, either use -U to provide the user name or use
>   -T for Trusted Connection usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile [-m maxerrors] [-f formatfile] [-e
>   errfile] [-F firstrow] [-L lastrow] [-b batchsize] [-n native type]
>   [-c character type] [-w wide character type] [-N keep non-text native]
>   [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier] [-C code page
>   specifier] [-t field terminator] [-r row terminator] [-i inputfile]
>   [-o outfile] [-a packetsize] [-S server name] [-U username] [-P
>   password] [-T trusted connection] [-v version] [-R regional enable]
>   [-k keep null values] [-E keep identity values] [-h "load hints"] [-x
>   generate xml format file] [-d database name] NULL

My procedure is this:

```
create procedure proc_generate_excel_with_columns
(
    @db_name    varchar(100),
    @table_name varchar(100),   
    @file_name  varchar(100)
)
as

--Generate column names as a recordset
declare @columns varchar(8000), @sql varchar(8000), @data_file varchar(100)
select 
    @columns=coalesce(@columns+',','')+column_name+' as '+column_name 

from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name='dbo.vcuriosoftronic.tblPayrollGroups'
select @columns=''''''+replace(replace(@columns,' as ',''''' as '),',',',''''')

--Create a dummy file to have actual data
select @data_file=substring('D:\TestFile.xls',1,len('D:\TestFile.xls')
                            -charindex('\',reverse('D:\TestFile.xls')))
                            +'D:\TestFile.xls'

--Generate column names in the passed EXCEL file
set @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp
          " select * from (select '+@columns+') as t"
          queryout "'+@file_name+'" -c'''
exec(@sql)

--Generate data in the dummy file
set @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp
         "select * from [myserver]..'+@table_name+'"
         queryout "'+@data_file+'" -c'''
exec(@sql)

--Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file
set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "'+@file_name+'"'''
exec(@sql)

--Delete dummy file 
set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Sounds like *whatever* your `proc_generate_excel_with_columns` is is using  xp_cmdshell to execute BCP incorrectly. This is impossible to answer without knowing what `proc_generate_excel_with_columns` is

Comment: kindly check my question again,I have now mentioned the procedure

Comment: You are missing -T or -U -P.  Try again ...  See my code below for a working example with AdventureWorks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my blog article on how to use BCP to export data.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1690

The below snippet uses the -T, trusted connection.  If you are running a job under the agent, it will run under that security account.

Please either pass the standard security credentials, -U -P or make sure the account has the ability to run the command.

```
-- BCP - Export query, pipe delimited format, trusted security, character format
DECLARE @bcp_cmd4 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @exe_path4 VARCHAR(200) = 
    ' cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\ & ';
SET @bcp_cmd4 =  @exe_path4 + 
    ' BCP.EXE "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.vSalesPerson" queryout ' +
    ' "C:\TEST\PEOPLE.TXT" -T -c -q -t0x7c -r\n';
PRINT @bcp_cmd4;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_cmd4;
GO
```

Updated assuming the BCP path is in search list.  Below is a screen shot with the path removed and the query changed for SQL Server 2012.

[image]

Look at the message window, it has the BCP command from the print statement.  You can put the command into a batch file to test from the DOS prompt.  It is a debugging exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks Crafty..but i have used -T in my procedure, which is mentioned in question.

Comment: It is not in the code above ...  That is why you are getting the message?  You have a data and column header dump.  Then a concatenation, and a removal of the data file.  But the bcp command is missing the type of credential ...

Comment: See bcp_cmd4.  It changes directory to the tool (bcp), at the end is all the options.  Notice after PEOPLE.TXT the -T.  Assuming bcp is in the path, -c -T.  The & is a nice way to have multiple DOS commands run in the same call.  Got to run, you should be all set ...

Comment: Error:The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
NULL

Comment: First, you have to make sure the directories exist (C:\test / C:\program files ...\.  Do they?  I did this example with SQL Server 2008 R2.  Also, AdventureWorks has to be installed as a test database.  Did you meet these requirements?  I think that is the error.  If bcp is in your path, comment out exe_path4 or remove everywhere.

Comment: instead of 'AdventureWorks' am using my tablename,but still isn't working

Comment: What is the error?  I can not help without screen shots, more info

Comment: Okay, the screen shot shows that the client configuration is not setup correctly.  IE- Shared Memory provider is not enabled.  Enable it, it should work.  This is all a configuration issue ... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190611(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to enable shared memory and am thankful that you answered my every query,really appreciate that!

Comment: Cna we export using aobve to xlsx?